# Unable to install 'pyreadline' using pip on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to uninstall 'pyreadline' python package from my windows system using

```
pip uninstall pyreadline-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

but it gives an error:

> Cannot uninstall 'pyreadline'. It is a distutils installed project and
>   thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which
>   would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: Your title says install, your question says uninstall. Please clarify. Also to uninstall a package the command would be `pip uninstall pyreadline`

Comment: I am trying to uninstall. And in case of wheel files pip uninstall with the entire wheel file name i.e., pyreadline-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl also works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you uninstall a python package that was installed using distutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402359/how-do-you-uninstall-a-python-package-that-was-installed-using-distutils)

Comment: @SubarnaSaha  Are you using Anaconda as your package manager? That might cause that message.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall
```

Now try:

```
pip uninstall pyreadline
```

Answer (score 0):

- `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==9.0.3`
- `pip uninstall pyreadline`
- `pip install --upgrade pip`

or

```
remove pyreadline package from lib (path\lib\site-packages\pyreadline )
```